# Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode7, keychain, ios-provisioning

while i am trying to build my project its giving me this error,i am using xcode 7 :

*what i was tried:*

Deleted the development and distribution certificated and then i have create it again.

about xcode ->preference->account->viewdetails ,in xcode 7 there is no refresh button is there.

[image]

```
Debug-iphoneos/Demofb.app: User canceled the operation.
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
```

in simulator its running.

but i don't know where problem is from keychainaccess or from the xcode.

Please anybody help me to solve this problem ,i am struggle here for more then half day.

Comment: there is no refresh button in Xcode7. If you download the new provision profiles, the delete files will automatically be removed. Have you added them in Code Signing Identity?

Comment: @AAA i have added new provisional in my code sign in...

Comment: @AAA after restart my system its working ,y its happens do u know

Comment: before restarting the system, have u tried cleaning the project and build?

Comment: yes but its gave me the same error mr. @AAA

Answer (score 1):

I surfed a bit and found the following things. Hope it helps you some way.

While choosing a signing identity, you have the choice of submitting your Mac app to the store, signing it with a Developer ID certificate to distribute it outside of the store, or not code signing it at all. If you select Mac App Store, you assign your Xcode project to a team and can enable app services, as described in Adding Capabilities. If you select Developer ID, you assign your Xcode project to a team but the available capabilities are limited (read Distributing Apps Outside the Mac App Store for how to create a Developer ID-signed app)

**Xcode detects when you’re missing a signing identity**. Typically, this happens when you move from one Mac to another or recreating the certificates and provision profiles. [Click here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingProfiles/MaintainingProfiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH30-SW26) to know more on provision profiles, but I am not sure this might not be your issue.

If you use the team provisioning profile that Xcode manages for you during development, as described in [Team Provisioning Profiles in Depth](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/LaunchingYourApponDevices/LaunchingYourApponDevices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH27-SW10), Xcode fixes code signing and provisioning issues for you before you attempt to build your app. In this case, you shouldn’t set the **Code Signing Identity** **build settings** yourself. However, if you want to use a custom development provisioning profile and set these build settings, as described in [Using Custom Provisioning Profiles](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingProfiles/MaintainingProfiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH30-SW65), you may encounter build issues described in this section. Common build errors tend to involve incorrect code signing identities.